# iOS - how to compare two ISO 8601 formatted times?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate, iso8601

I want to check if a time such as "2011-03-29T15:57:02.680-04:00" is before the current time. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The great thing about ISO8601 date and time formats is that you can simply compare the strings alphabetically. So you can write the current time to an NSString in ISO8601 format and then use NSString's `compare` method on the two strings.

However, it's often better to compare `NSDate` objects. I use two helper functions to convert between an ISO date string and an NSDate using `strftime` and `strptime` -- these functions just do the `yyyy-mm-dd` part, but you should be able to extend them easily enough:

```
NSString* ISOStringWithDate(NSDate* date)
{
    char buf[11];  // Enough space for "yyyy-mm-dd\000"
    time_t clock = [date timeIntervalSince1970];
    struct tm time;
    gmtime_r(&clock, &time);
    strftime_l(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d", &time, NULL);
    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:buf];
}

NSDate* dateWithISOString(NSString* dateString)
{
    struct tm time;
    memset(&time, 0, sizeof(time));
    if (!strptime_l([dateString UTF8String], "%Y-%m-%d", &time, NULL))
    {
        return nil;
    }
    time_t clock = timegm(&time);
    return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:clock];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use Peter Hosey's [`ISO8601DateFormatter`](http://boredzo.org/iso8601unparser/) class to parse it into an `NSDate` object and then compare that with `[NSDate date]`.

An example:

```
NSString *iso8601String = ...;
ISO8601DateFormatter *formatter = [[ISO8601DateFormatter alloc] init];
NSDate *isoDate = [formatter dateFromString:iso8601String];
[formatter release]; //if you're not using ARC

BOOL isBeforeCurrent = [[NSDate date] compare:isoDate] == NSOrderedAscending;
```

Comment: is there a simpler way to do it? I don't want to use libraries if possible

Comment: @Suchi I'm afraid that I can't think of an easier way at the moment.

Comment: @Suchi: As the source is available, you can always use the code within Hosey's library as an example of how to do what you want (rather than use the library itself). However... you'll probably find that it's not worth reinventing the wheel, as he's done the work required to convert such dates (and the default API has not).  Not being snide; I actually ran into this same problem, and ended up using a similar library rather than writing my own.